# Bootstrap 3 Slide in Menu / Navbar on Mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am building a browser-based mobile app and I've decided to use Bootstrap 3 as the css framework for the design. Bootstrap 3 comes with a great "responsive" feature in the navigation bar where it collapses automatically if it detects a specific "break point" regarding the resolution of the browser. It works in a lot of situations.

But have you noticed lately how a lot of browser-based mobile apps have the primary navigation hidden out of the left of the screen, and when the toggle icon is pressed (toggled) in the top-right corner, the primary navigation slides out to the right about 2/3 of the way into the screen? This is an increasingly popular solution for navigating through browser-based apps on mobile devices and I think in theory it should be pretty easy to modify bootstrap css/js to accommodate this version of the navigation collapse feature.

How can these feature be implemented? It seems like it shouldn't take too much modification. I'd really like to hear your thoughts/solutions on this matter. Also, I think it would be a great long-term solution for Bootstrap to implement as a built-in feature.

Unfortunately I have not made any attempts to create this feature because while I am familiar with these technologies, I am predominantly a PHP/MySQL developer and I believe a feature as useful as this should be built by experts with insight that I don't have as a front-end developer.

Comment: Please include your current CSS/HTML Markup. Also, "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. **Include attempted solutions,** why they didn't work, and the expected results."

Comment: I did this recently, there's a lot involved as many things have to happen, especially if the navigation is fixed, it has to un-fix when it slides in or you won't be able to reach longer menus. I use Boostrap all the time but not their menu, you can add slide in menus on your own and modify them as well. http://jsbin.com/eHAfIhI/1/edit

Comment: When you look at the CSS you'll notice that the min-width kicks in at the default Bootstrap which is 768px. Notice that adjustments were made to the form at max-width because it would look crappy otherwise. Plus percentages were used as the smallest device is 240px.

Comment: There is a popular Bootstrap fork - Jasny Bootstrap. The fork has out of the box various off-canvas implementations (slide-in, push, reveal):
http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#offcanvas

Comment: This is a solution that you need:
[Bootstrap - How to slide nav bar from left instead from top](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37694851/996010)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap - How to slide nav bar from left instead from top](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31641352/bootstrap-how-to-slide-nav-bar-from-left-instead-from-top)

Comment: It is an UI pattern called Drawer https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Comment: We start using _slideout.js_ It isn´t directly using Bootstrap as it is Dependency-free. But you can combine it with bootstrap and for example show the slideout button only when the website is shown on a mobile device. You can find it [here](https://slideout.js.org/) or [here](https://github.com/Mango/slideout).

Comment: You may also be interested in this jQuery plugin and CSS framework: https://myflashlabs.github.io/24component-bars/ It helps you create a fully responsive off-canvas navigation, and lots of other menu types which are suitable for different kinds of projects. You don't need to code it yourself all from the beginning when there's already a solution out there!

Answer (score 138):

This was for my own project and I'm sharing it here too.

### DEMO: http://jsbin.com/OjOTIGaP/1/edit

This one had trouble after 3.2, so the one below may work better for you:

### https://jsbin.com/seqola/2/edit --- BETTER VERSION, slightly

---

**CSS**

```
/* adjust body when menu is open */
body.slide-active {
    overflow-x: hidden
}
/*first child of #page-content so it doesn't shift around*/
.no-margin-top {
    margin-top: 0px!important
}
/*wrap the entire page content but not nav inside this div if not a fixed top, don't add any top padding */
#page-content {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 70px;
    left: 0;
}
#page-content.slide-active {
    padding-top: 0
}
/* put toggle bars on the left :: not using button */
#slide-nav .navbar-toggle {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 0;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    width: 30px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    border: 0;
    background: transparent;
}
/* icon bar prettyup - optional */
#slide-nav .navbar-toggle > .icon-bar {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}
#slide-nav .navbar-toggle.slide-active .icon-bar {
    background: orange
}
.navbar-header {
    position: relative
}
/* un fix the navbar when active so that all the menu items are accessible */
.navbar.navbar-fixed-top.slide-active {
    position: relative
}
/* screw writing importants and shit, just stick it in max width since these classes are not shared between sizes */
@media (max-width:767px) { 
    #slide-nav .container {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0!important;
    }
    #slide-nav .navbar-header {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0 15px;
    }
    #slide-nav .navbar.slide-active {
        position: absolute;
        width: 80%;
        top: -1px;
        z-index: 1000;
    }
    #slide-nav #slidemenu {
        background: #f7f7f7;
        left: -100%;
        width: 80%;
        min-width: 0;
        position: absolute;
        padding-left: 0;
        z-index: 2;
        top: -8px;
        margin: 0;
    }
    #slide-nav #slidemenu .navbar-nav {
        min-width: 0;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }
    #slide-nav #slidemenu .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu li a {
        min-width: 0;
        width: 80%;
        white-space: normal;
    }
    #slide-nav {
        border-top: 0
    }
    #slide-nav.navbar-inverse #slidemenu {
        background: #333
    }
    /* this is behind the navigation but the navigation is not inside it so that the navigation is accessible and scrolls*/
    #slide-nav #navbar-height-col {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 80%;
        left: -80%;
        background: #eee;
    }
    #slide-nav.navbar-inverse #navbar-height-col {
        background: #333;
        z-index: 1;
        border: 0;
    }
    #slide-nav .navbar-form {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 8px 0;
        text-align: center;
        overflow: hidden;
        /*fast clearfixer*/
    }
    #slide-nav .navbar-form .form-control {
        text-align: center
    }
    #slide-nav .navbar-form .btn {
        width: 100%
    }
}
@media (min-width:768px) { 
    #page-content {
        left: 0!important
    }
    .navbar.navbar-fixed-top.slide-active {
        position: fixed
    }
    .navbar-header {
        left: 0!important
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="slide-nav">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-toggle"> 
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </a>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
   </div>
   <div id="slidemenu">
     
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="search" placeholder="search" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
          </form>
     
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
     <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
       <li class="divider"></li>
       <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
       <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
       <li class="divider"></li>
       <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
       <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
       <li class="divider"></li>
       <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
       <li><a href="#">Separated link test long title goes here</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
          
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    //stick in the fixed 100% height behind the navbar but don't wrap it
    $('#slide-nav.navbar .container').append($('<div id="navbar-height-col"></div>'));

    // Enter your ids or classes
    var toggler = '.navbar-toggle';
    var pagewrapper = '#page-content';
    var navigationwrapper = '.navbar-header';
    var menuwidth = '100%'; // the menu inside the slide menu itself
    var slidewidth = '80%';
    var menuneg = '-100%';
    var slideneg = '-80%';


    $("#slide-nav").on("click", toggler, function (e) {

        var selected = $(this).hasClass('slide-active');

        $('#slidemenu').stop().animate({
            left: selected ? menuneg : '0px'
        });

        $('#navbar-height-col').stop().animate({
            left: selected ? slideneg : '0px'
        });

        $(pagewrapper).stop().animate({
            left: selected ? '0px' : slidewidth
        });

        $(navigationwrapper).stop().animate({
            left: selected ? '0px' : slidewidth
        });


        $(this).toggleClass('slide-active', !selected);
        $('#slidemenu').toggleClass('slide-active');


        $('#page-content, .navbar, body, .navbar-header').toggleClass('slide-active');


    });


    var selected = '#slidemenu, #page-content, body, .navbar, .navbar-header';


    $(window).on("resize", function () {

        if ($(window).width() > 767 && $('.navbar-toggle').is(':hidden')) {
            $(selected).removeClass('slide-active');
        }


    });

});
```

Comment: Any way to make this responsive so that on a desktop, the navbar displays under a splash graphic but on the mobile device, the navbar looks like this sidebar?

Comment: Yes. you would design within the min-widths

Comment: That was for my own project and I'm sharing it this way. Any support, further help, etc., is up to each individual.

Comment: Cab, thank you so much this is truly an incredible contribution!! I have since done some more research and found features in the sencha framework that are much closer (but still not quite perfect) to the features I had in mind. Particularly, the facebook app on android, sencha calls the animation a "reveal"/"cover".

I noticed a couple of differences between the current version of your example and the animations in the sencha framework (or the facebook app). One in particular is that the left-hand menu when it is open and the primary content on the right scroll together in tandem. (1)

Comment: On the facebook app the left-hand menu and the main content area scroll independently of one another and can ideally be loaded/reloaded independently as well. Is this possible to do with the bootstrap framework? Also in the bootstrap example these two content areas shift/slide next to each other and do not overlap. Also, I would like to avoid the horizontal scroll-bar from being visible/available whenever the left-hand menu is toggled. I hope these features are making sense! :) Thanks again for all your help and insight! (2)

Comment: This could be a good starting point to get some jQuery and CSS under your belt. Try some things and then post your efforts on SO. The overflow-x: hidden; on the body will prevent horizontal scrollbars, BUT if your site is not fluidly responsive this can cause issues. There's no other way around that unless the site is responsive, using percentages for the container or .container-fluid in the next release of bootstrap.

Comment: Great example as a starting point, although I have to point out that it does cut off content in the left navbar when it's height is greater then the main content. I'm trying to work out a solution right now and will be back if I get anywhere.

Comment: This works beautifully thank you! I included the css and js as separate files in my code and even call this via requirejs. I only had to make minimal modifications to my existing bootstrap navigation markup. You have made an exceedingly complex task trivial and that is impressive. You should make this available as a bootstrap plugin. Are you open sourcing this? Github?

Comment: Feel free to refine it and send out there. I abandoned this and am using another idea

Comment: Nice code, one problem: when you scroll down and open the menu, you can't see it since it's at the top of the page, anyway of handle this?

Comment: Use a different solution if you don't want to adjust the jquery and css. I have stopped using Bootstrap.

Answer (score 67):

**Bootstrap 5 Beta 3 (update 2021)**

Introducing the new [Bootstrap 5 Offcanvas Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65501628/bootstrap-5-off-canvas-missing-css-js/65506255#65506255)

**Bootstrap 4**

[Create a responsive navbar sidebar "drawer" in Bootstrap 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48996084/create-a-responsive-navbar-sidebar-drawer-in-bootstrap-4M)
[Bootstrap horizontal menu collapse to sidemenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49527465/bootstrap-horizontal-menu-collapse-to-sidemenu/49535297#49535297)

**Bootstrap 3**

I think what you're looking for is generally known as an "off-canvas" layout. Here is the standard off-canvas example from the official Bootstrap docs: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/

The "official" example uses a right-side sidebar the toggle off and on separately from the top navbar menu. I also found these off-canvas variations that slide in from the left and may be closer to what you're looking for..

http://www.bootstrapzero.com/bootstrap-template/off-canvas-sidebar
http://www.bootstrapzero.com/bootstrap-template/facebook

Comment: This off-canvas example is really great too! This is closer to what I was looking for, but a couple of points that I had made in my comments to Cab's post are still prevalent. The side-menu and the main content area do not scroll independently. Also it is more of a slide left/right than a cover/reveal animation. Let me know what you think! :) Thanks again so much for your contribution Skelly! This thread has been incredibly insightful and helpful!

Comment: EDIT: I just saw now the facebook version you posed does scroll independently from the primary content area! Also, I was wondering if it could be totally invisible by default, regardless of the current browser resolution, and have it be toggled by that icon that is at the top-right of this example. And that toggle button moved to the top-left? Is this possible? That would be pretty much exactly what I would need to move forward with this project. The only problem I've seen is that the horizontal scroll bar is displayed when you toggle the menu. There's got to be a way to prevent that too.

Comment: Glad these helped. I'm sure it's possible to achieve what you want, but it will take some tweaking. I'd recommend playing with the Bootply (http://bootply.com/96266). You should be able to adjust the breakpoint for the sidebar by adjusting the media query `@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {` .. in the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Without Plugin, we can do this; bootstrap multi-level responsive menu for mobile phone with slide toggle for mobile:

```js
$('[data-toggle="slide-collapse"]').on('click', function() {
  $navMenuCont = $($(this).data('target'));
  $navMenuCont.animate({
    'width': 'toggle'
  }, 350);
  $(".menu-overlay").fadeIn(500);
});

$(".menu-overlay").click(function(event) {
  $(".navbar-toggle").trigger("click");
  $(".menu-overlay").fadeOut(500);
});

// if ($(window).width() >= 767) {
//     $('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
//         $(this).find('>.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
//     }, function() {
//         $(this).find('>.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
//     });

//     $('ul.nav li.dropdown-submenu').hover(function() {
//         $(this).find('>.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
//     }, function() {
//         $(this).find('>.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
//     });


//     $('ul.dropdown-menu [data-toggle=dropdown]').on('click', function(event) {
//         event.preventDefault();
//         event.stopPropagation();
//         $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('open');
//         $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
//         $('b', this).toggleClass("caret caret-up");
//     });
// }

// $(window).resize(function() {
//     if( $(this).width() >= 767) {
//         $('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
//             $(this).find('>.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
//         }, function() {
//             $(this).find('>.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
//         });
//     }
// });

var windowWidth = $(window).width();
if (windowWidth > 767) {
  // $('ul.dropdown-menu [data-toggle=dropdown]').on('click', function(event) {
  //     event.preventDefault();
  //     event.stopPropagation();
  //     $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('open');
  //     $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
  //     $('b', this).toggleClass("caret caret-up");
  // });

  $('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('>.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
  }, function() {
    $(this).find('>.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
  });

  $('ul.nav li.dropdown-submenu').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('>.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
  }, function() {
    $(this).find('>.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
  });


  $('ul.dropdown-menu [data-toggle=dropdown]').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('open');
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
    // $('b', this).toggleClass("caret caret-up");
  });
}
if (windowWidth < 767) {
  $('ul.dropdown-menu [data-toggle=dropdown]').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('open');
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
    // $('b', this).toggleClass("caret caret-up");
  });
}

// $('.dropdown a').append('Some text');
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #slide-navbar-collapse {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 15px;
    z-index: 999999;
    width: 280px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    overflow: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    max-height: inherit;
  }
  .menu-overlay {
    display: none;
    background-color: #000;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    /* IE7 & 8 */
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 49;
  }
  .navbar-fixed-top {
    position: initial !important;
  }
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }
  ul.nav.navbar-nav li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  }
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header,
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 15px;
  }
}

.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -1px;
}

li.dropdown a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

li.dropdown>a:before {
  content: "\f107";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  top: 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

li.dropdown-submenu>a:before {
  content: "\f107";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  top: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

ul.dropdown-menu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: none !important;
}

li.dropdown.open {
  border-bottom: 0px !important;
}

li.dropdown-submenu.open {
  border-bottom: 0px !important;
}

li.dropdown-submenu>a {
  font-weight: bold !important;
}

li.dropdown>a {
  font-weight: bold !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  font-weight: bold !important;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 15px;
}

li.dropdown>a:before {
  content: "\f107";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  top: 9px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 767px) {
  li.dropdown-submenu>a {
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 15px;
  }
  li.dropdown>a:before {
    content: "\f107";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    position: absolute;
    right: 3px;
    top: 12px;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="slide-collapse" data-target="#slide-navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="slide-navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                  <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">SubMenu 1</span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                      <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">SubMenu 2</span></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
    <div class="menu-overlay"></div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1>Resize the window to see the result</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus non bibendum sem, et sodales massa. Proin quis velit vel nisl imperdiet rhoncus vitae id tortor. Praesent blandit tellus in enim sollicitudin rutrum. Integer ullamcorper, augue ut tristique
        ultrices, augue magna placerat ex, ac varius mauris ante sed dui. Fusce ullamcorper vulputate magna, a malesuada nunc pellentesque sit amet. Donec posuere placerat erat, sed ornare enim aliquam vitae. Nullam pellentesque auctor augue, vel commodo
        dolor porta ac. Sed libero eros, fringilla ac lorem in, blandit scelerisque lorem. Suspendisse iaculis justo velit, sit amet fringilla velit ornare a. Sed consectetur quam eget ipsum luctus bibendum. Ut nisi lectus, viverra vitae ipsum sit amet,
        condimentum condimentum neque. In maximus suscipit eros ut eleifend. Donec venenatis mauris nulla, ac bibendum metus bibendum vel.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus non bibendum sem, et sodales massa. Proin quis velit vel nisl imperdiet rhoncus vitae id tortor. Praesent blandit tellus in enim sollicitudin rutrum. Integer ullamcorper, augue ut tristique
        ultrices, augue magna placerat ex, ac varius mauris ante sed dui. Fusce ullamcorper vulputate magna, a malesuada nunc pellentesque sit amet. Donec posuere placerat erat, sed ornare enim aliquam vitae. Nullam pellentesque auctor augue, vel commodo
        dolor porta ac. Sed libero eros, fringilla ac lorem in, blandit scelerisque lorem. Suspendisse iaculis justo velit, sit amet fringilla velit ornare a. Sed consectetur quam eget ipsum luctus bibendum. Ut nisi lectus, viverra vitae ipsum sit amet,
        condimentum condimentum neque. In maximus suscipit eros ut eleifend. Donec venenatis mauris nulla, ac bibendum metus bibendum vel.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus non bibendum sem, et sodales massa. Proin quis velit vel nisl imperdiet rhoncus vitae id tortor. Praesent blandit tellus in enim sollicitudin rutrum. Integer ullamcorper, augue ut tristique
        ultrices, augue magna placerat ex, ac varius mauris ante sed dui. Fusce ullamcorper vulputate magna, a malesuada nunc pellentesque sit amet. Donec posuere placerat erat, sed ornare enim aliquam vitae. Nullam pellentesque auctor augue, vel commodo
        dolor porta ac. Sed libero eros, fringilla ac lorem in, blandit scelerisque lorem. Suspendisse iaculis justo velit, sit amet fringilla velit ornare a. Sed consectetur quam eget ipsum luctus bibendum. Ut nisi lectus, viverra vitae ipsum sit amet,
        condimentum condimentum neque. In maximus suscipit eros ut eleifend. Donec venenatis mauris nulla, ac bibendum metus bibendum vel.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus non bibendum sem, et sodales massa. Proin quis velit vel nisl imperdiet rhoncus vitae id tortor. Praesent blandit tellus in enim sollicitudin rutrum. Integer ullamcorper, augue ut tristique
        ultrices, augue magna placerat ex, ac varius mauris ante sed dui. Fusce ullamcorper vulputate magna, a malesuada nunc pellentesque sit amet. Donec posuere placerat erat, sed ornare enim aliquam vitae. Nullam pellentesque auctor augue, vel commodo
        dolor porta ac. Sed libero eros, fringilla ac lorem in, blandit scelerisque lorem. Suspendisse iaculis justo velit, sit amet fringilla velit ornare a. Sed consectetur quam eget ipsum luctus bibendum. Ut nisi lectus, viverra vitae ipsum sit amet,
        condimentum condimentum neque. In maximus suscipit eros ut eleifend. Donec venenatis mauris nulla, ac bibendum metus bibendum vel.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus non bibendum sem, et sodales massa. Proin quis velit vel nisl imperdiet rhoncus vitae id tortor. Praesent blandit tellus in enim sollicitudin rutrum. Integer ullamcorper, augue ut tristique
        ultrices, augue magna placerat ex, ac varius mauris ante sed dui. Fusce ullamcorper vulputate magna, a malesuada nunc pellentesque sit amet. Donec posuere placerat erat, sed ornare enim aliquam vitae. Nullam pellentesque auctor augue, vel commodo
        dolor porta ac. Sed libero eros, fringilla ac lorem in, blandit scelerisque lorem. Suspendisse iaculis justo velit, sit amet fringilla velit ornare a. Sed consectetur quam eget ipsum luctus bibendum. Ut nisi lectus, viverra vitae ipsum sit amet,
        condimentum condimentum neque. In maximus suscipit eros ut eleifend. Donec venenatis mauris nulla, ac bibendum metus bibendum vel.
      </p>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

[Reference JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/syamacl45/x507ndp3/)