# How to create a Vertical Nav Bar in HTML as on Youtube or Medium.com

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigationbar

I am trying to emulate a vertical nav-bar as shown on [Medium](http://medium.com) i.e. Menu is hidden left on some 'click' and when visible shifts page to the `right`.
I can create Vertical Menu but I'm clueless about this effect.
I am using Bootstrap, Jquery and Angular.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as the "off canvas" effect.

You can study this template:  [Bootply Off Canvas side.](http://www.bootply.com/render/88026)
You may also want to look into this question/answer:  [css - Bootstrap 3 slide in Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20863288/bootstrap-3-slide-in-menu-navbar-on-mobile)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you put it into divs and make them hidden or visible with JavaScript?
Try this.

```
<html>
<div id="Page1">
//content here
</div>

<div id="Page2">
//content here
</div>
</html>
```

.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var div = document.getElementById('Page1');
// hide
div.style.visibility = 'hidden';
// OR
div.style.display = 'none';

// show
div.style.visibility = 'visible';
// OR
</script>
div.style.display = 'block';
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
var div = document.getElementById('Page2');
// hide
div.style.visibility = 'hidden';
// OR
div.style.display = 'none';

// show
div.style.visibility = 'visible';
// OR
</script>
div.style.display = 'block';
</script>
```