# Responsive Bootstrap Push Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i m trying to create Responsive Bootstrap Push Menu , i have created this templete and this for computer  [image]

and for mobile it look like this [image]

so when we click dropdown it should push to the left side and show the dropdown menu list

this is code i have tried

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container
                <div class="navbar-header">
                 <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2" style="height:30px;margin-top:5px;">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle toggle-menu menu-left push-body" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-8" style="height:30px;margin-top:5px;">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="email" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2" style="height:30px;margin-top:5px;">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse cbp-spmenu cbp-spmenu-vertical cbp-spmenu-left" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
<script src="js/jPushMenu.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      //<![CDATA[
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.toggle-menu').jPushMenu({closeOnClickLink: false});
        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
      });
      //]]>
    </script>
```

but i m not able to push to left side.

Comment: That email input needs a label. http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H44.html

Answer (score 1):

Is this something you looking for

http://jsfiddle.net/w6qc954t/

your template http://jsfiddle.net/w6qc954t/2/

its using jPushMenu.js by takien at github other than follwing part is include in that js

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  $('.cbp-spmenu').v2p({
    height:'100vh'
  });
});

$(window).resize(); // trigger event so it shows on load
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.toggle-menu').jPushMenu({closeOnClickLink: false});
        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
      });
```

Comment: ,yes i used this file jPushMenu.js butits not working

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered here already, use an "off canvas" layout provided for in Bootstrap code: [Bootstrap 3 Slide in Menu / Navbar on Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20863288/bootstrap-3-slide-in-menu-navbar-on-mobile).