# Looking for a jquery slide out menu as that of opencart admin

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, opencart

I have been looking for jquery menu as that of opencart admin.

[image]

when collapsed

[image]

Is there an example which i can look into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search them from the following links.

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/nav-sidebar-with-toggle-button

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13919

http://alijafarian.com/jquery-horizontal-slideout-menu/

[Bootstrap 3 Slide in Menu / Navbar on Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20863288/bootstrap-3-slide-in-menu-navbar-on-mobile)

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/17/slide-and-push-menus/

http://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Cool-Animated-Side-Menus-with-Sliding-Pushing-Effects.html