# Bootstrap 5 Off Canvas Missing CSS/JS

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to use bootstrap 5's off canvas.
The css & js associated with the plugin do not seem to be included in the framework.

https://deploy-preview-29017--twbs-bootstrap.netlify.app/docs/5.0/components/offcanvas/

The demo on the BS website works; However, the github link on the BS website goes to a 404.
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/site/content/docs/5.0/components/offcanvas.md

Comment: Please accept the answer so others know the question is solved!

Answer (score 8):

**Bootstap 5 beta 3 (Update 2021)**

Bootstrap has finally introduced an **official Offcanvas component**! From the offical blog...

> "..the offcanvas comes with configurable backdrop, body scroll, and
> placement. Offcanvas components can be placed on the left, right, and
> bottom of the viewport..."

[Bootstrap Offcanvas demo](https://codeply.com/p/xsxI3YKDST)

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasExample" aria-controls="offcanvasExample">
    Open Sidebar
</button>
<div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasExample" aria-labelledby="offcanvasExampleLabel">
    <div class="offcanvas-header">
        <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasExampleLabel">Offcanvas</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close text-reset" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="offcanvas-body">
        <div> Some text as placeholder. In real life you can have the elements you have chosen. Like, text, images, lists, etc. </div>
        <div class="dropdown mt-3">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"> Dropdown button </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Read more](https://dev.to/codeply/bootstrap-finally-has-an-off-canvas-component-41dl)

---

**Bootstap 5 beta 2 (Original answer)**

As you can see in the [official Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/), there is not (yet) a Off-canvas component in Bootstrap 5 beta. The netlify docs you referenced are based on an older pre-alpha build.

The Bootstrap 5 examples do show an **experimental** off-canvas layout, but like the other examples it requires extra custom CSS and JS that can be [found here in the Bootstrap GH repo](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/main/site/content/docs/5.0/examples/offcanvas-navbar)

Once you include the extra CSS/JS, the [off-canvas example works as expected](https://www.codeply.com/p/EjawRXuBqV).

Comment: github link is not working. Could you update the correct link?

Comment: very cool effect and the easiest Solutions out there to create a sidebar! thanks for the example.