# Bootstrap 5 Off Canvas sizing issue

Tags: html, css, sass, bootstrap-5, off-canvas-menu

I'm using **bootstrap 5 off-canvas** for collapsing and in same time I have an announcement bar it's just an **dismissible alert** on top of my navbar.

> the question is my off-canvas top size not working good when I click
> to close button on dismissible alert.

how I can fix this ?? I made a live example on [codepen.Io](https://codepen.io/themes4all/pen/QWGyWPq)

> Note : try to resize the window and close the alert to see the issue
> that I have in my off-canvas.

**HTML / CSS / JS :**

```js
    (function () {
      'use strict'
      
      // for Off-Canvas Menu
      
      document.querySelector('[data-bs-toggle="offcanvas"]').addEventListener('click', function () {
        document.querySelector('.offcanvas-collapse').classList.toggle('open')
      })
    })()
```

```css
    @media (max-width: 991.98px) {
      .offcanvas-collapse {
        position: fixed;
        top: 56px; /* Height of navbar */
        bottom: 0;
        left: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
        overflow-y: auto;
        visibility: hidden;
        background-color: #343a40;
        transition: transform .3s ease-in-out, visibility .3s ease-in-out;
      }
      .offcanvas-collapse.open {
        visibility: visible;
        transform: translateX(-100%);
      }
    }
```

```html
 <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Bootstrap 5 off-canvas</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
    
    
    <!-- Alert -->
    
      <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible fade show px-0 mb-0 text-start text-lg-center" role="alert">
        <div class="container-lg">
            <strong>Note!</strong> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Second Navbar -->
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary sticky-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse offcanvas-collapse">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="d-flex">
            <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-light" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    
    <main class="container py-5">
    
    <h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>
    
    <p class="lead">
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
    
    <h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>
    
    <p class="lead">
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
    
    <h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>
    
    <p class="lead">
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
    
    <h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>
    
    <p class="lead">
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
    
    <h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>
    
    <p class="lead">
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
    
    <h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>
    
    <p class="lead">
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
    
    <h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>
    
    <p class="lead">
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
    
    <h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>
    
    <p class="lead">
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
    
    <h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>
    
    <p class="lead">
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
    
    <h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>
    
    <p class="lead">
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
    
    <h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>
    
    <p class="lead">
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
    
    <h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>
    
    <p class="lead">
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
    
    </main>
    
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It's like you're combining Navbar and Offcanvas.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're correctly using the [Offcanvas component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/offcanvas/)...

Markup:

```
<div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvas" aria-labelledby="offcanvasLabel">
  <div class="offcanvas-header">
    <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasLabel">Offcanvas</h5>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close text-reset" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="offcanvas-body">
    Content for the offcanvas goes here. You can place just about any Bootstrap component or custom elements here.
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var offcanvasElementList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.offcanvas'))
var offcanvasList = offcanvasElementList.map(function (offcanvasEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Offcanvas(offcanvasEl)
})
```

Also see: [Bootstrap 5 Off Canvas Missing CSS/JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65501628/bootstrap-5-off-canvas-missing-css-js/65506255#65506255)